# Issue with uname when trying to launch atom from MSYS shell

Tags: git, atom-editor, uname

I have recently installed Atom, and made sure the path is correct, however, when calling any command such as atom file_name, or atom . I am met with

```
uname: invalid option -- o
Try "uname --help" for more information.
"esources" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tested windows default cmd and it launches atom without an issue, and based on the error, somehow resources got renamed to esources, however I am completely lost as to where I would got rectify this issue.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

And if I do run `uname -a` I get

```
MINGW32_NT-6.2 COMP_NAME 1.0.12(0.46/3/2) 2012-07-05 14:56 i686 unknown
```

Comment: any chance youve found a solution yet?

Comment: @JayS. I ended up switching to a dual boot of Linux for my dev Environment, as it had far fewer issues than my Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's going on here is the version of uname (uname.exe) that you have doesn't have the "-o" (--operating-system) option. I ran into this issue as well, but have another machine where running atom from bash on windows was working so I copied the uname.exe over to the correct location on the machine that wasn't working and it worked like a charm.

To find where uname is you can run "where uname". You can check the version using "uname --version". The version that is working for me is 5.97 (I didn't check the version before replacing it).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the obsolete MSYS.

Try using MSYS2, which provides up to date versions of pretty much anything and most likely does not show this problem.